# UICollectionView intercepting touches

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, touches

I have a UICollectionView with a custom layout and in my view controller I do:

```
[self.collectionView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    NSLog(@"TOUCHED");
}
```

but that method never gets called. I was previously using a tableviewcontroller in conjunction with a navigation controller and I set multiple touch enabled on the nav controllers view and all was good but now I switched the tableview out with the collection view and touches are never captured.

Answer (score 0):

You could use UIGestureRecoginzer to intercept a gesture. It also has to have multiple touch enabled, but it gets more specific to what touch you want to capture.